# Multiple errors when trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, lenovo

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu 23.10 in a ThinkPad P15 with a Quadro T2000, but when I enter "Try or Install Ubuntu", the screen shows the Lenovo logo with the one from Ubuntu below, if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key I can see what I think are the logs of what is currently happening.

Everything succeeds, but there is an error in **udisks2.service** like this:

```
Failed to start udisks2.service - Disk Manager.   
See "systemctl status udisks2.service" for details.
```

Then, when the GUI starts it says that a problem has occurred with details saying that **udisks2.service** has failed because of stack smashing.

I can install Ubuntu with these errors, but they continue to appear when I'm using it until there is a white screen saying that the system can't recover and I need to log in again.

Things I've tried:

- I tried to use the USB on other devices without errors.
- Disabled Secure Boot in Lenovo UEFI setup utility.
- Connected to the internet to do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- Wiped the disk completely.
- `journalctl` of **udisks2.service** shows errors mainly in the stack smashing.